# How to get 3rd party cookies?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I am working on a service that would listen for URLs, visit each of them and get cookies for each request.

Currently I have something like this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://google.com')
cookies = browser.get_cookies()

#parse cookies
```

However, this only gives me 1st party cookies, but I also need to get 3rd party cookies. I found out that Selenium web drivers don't support this. I would like to know how can I achieve this? I'm not limited to Selenium, so would appreciate other solutions.

Comment: Here's how to do it in javascript: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-get-all-cookies/

Comment: @mitchfish36: I need to do it with Python, but nonetheless, your example can get only 1st party cookies (cookies that are set from the same domain).
My current solution is to use proxy and check for Set-Cookie header on responses, but I would rather use something less complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
r = s.get('http://google.com')
r = s.get('http://facebook.net')
for cookie in s.cookies:
    print(cookie)
```

http://python-requests.org/

---

Using: Selenium + PhantomJS

```
from selenium import webdriver

cookie_file_path = 'cookie.txt'

args = ['--cookies-file={}'.format(cookie_file_path)]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=args)
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.get('http://facebook.com')
with open(cookie_file_path) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output (wrapped):

```
[General]
cookies="@Variant(\0\0\0\x7f\0\0\0\x16QList<QNetworkCookie>\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\a\0
\0\0\xd6NID=67=SZetUV-oLq_M8ik40VT2GEIb45LMaXkhm6H3zx1wULO52qkCHPc9AML_p5eubW4zL
Ms158YAYKQTdCJzb4mInix_Zek6P8Ej1XZh9h5Ng3I7X4gZuE_S-Fl2YpaSYd9B; HttpOnly; expir
es=Wed, 18-Dec-2013 02:44:31 GMT; domain=.google.co.kr; path=/\0\0\0ldatr=kMm_Ue
0P06lxFANs8c-wCgwG; HttpOnly; expires=Thu, 18-Jun-2015 02:44:32 GMT; domain=.fac
ebook.com; path=/\0\0\0Kreg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; domain=.f
acebook.com; path=/\0\0\0Jreg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F; domain=.
facebook.com; path=/\0\0\0\xa2PREF=ID=be651672f1ddac52:U=515e3545a8a53080:FF=0:T
M=1371523471:LM=1371524047:S=iqfF3qNRUwVsInZR; expires=Thu, 18-Jun-2015 02:54:07
 GMT; domain=.google.com; path=/\0\0\0\xd4NID=67=pm8Ws9703eugHhhImX_hBpqhUyAhCUG
TebjDZ6YY_cP7CuvIA4x8ElgGaj6tOweXFxxjALoX1PwqFvHHkUY1kerw3vwM-VaIyyPVSADMqOnR-Ty
ed_bGU3bk6YSwUUeG; HttpOnly; expires=Wed, 18-Dec-2013 02:54:07 GMT; domain=.goog
le.com; path=/\0\0\0\xa9PREF=ID=9769c9a2d96728cf:U=3d59c2548337b74e:FF=0:NW=1:TM
=1371523471:LM=1371524047:S=vE5Y_06LhP4unse7; expires=Thu, 18-Jun-2015 02:54:07
 GMT; domain=.google.co.kr; path=/)"
```

Comment: This only gets 1st party cookies sent by server. I also need cookies set from javascript.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions, Selenium + PhanthomJS and Selenium + Google Chrome work. With Google Chrome you don't even need cookie file, because .get_cookies() retrieves cookies for all domains.

Comment: get_cookies() only get the cookies from the first-party domain, not the third-party domain