# How do I get all third party cookies with Scrapy or other easier methods?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, scrapy, web-crawler

I wish to use Python Scrapy to get all cookies on a domain, including third party cookies such as embedded videos or Google Calender.

I first used Scrapy to check "Set-Cookie" Field in HTTP headers, but I was only able to get first party cookies.

Then I tried Scrapy+Selenium+Chromedriver to load all js to get all cookies. However, this is very slow. I found this post and tried PhantomJS: [How to get 3rd party cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146514/how-to-get-3rd-party-cookies) I did the same thing, but I got an empty cookie.txt file.

I am wondering whether there is any easy way to get all cookies from a website, or how I should fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link below should be able to help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146514/how-to-get-3rd-party-cookies

Comment: @Gozie Thanks for your reply, but I read this post before, as I mentioned in the post. Chromdriver does the work but it's very slow, while PhantomJS can't get third party cookies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most python scraping tools are never going to do a complete job of getting cookies as it is unable to execute javascript and many (perhaps most) third-party cookies are set directly or indirectly by scripts.

You therefore need to use some sort of browser automation which you seem to be doing.  In regards to phantomjs, it most certainly *does* return all cookies via its API, if you are having trouble keep trying.  As far as selenium+chromedriver goes, it will only return first-party cookies.  PhantomJS is actually the best option strictly for gathering cookies.  Another option is to create fresh profiles for chrome/firefox in selenium, find the temporary files path, and opening the cookie database directly with sqlite.

You can also try a tool like webxray which is designed to capture third-party requests and cookies: https://github.com/timlib/webXray (disclosure: I wrote it).

Comment: Thank you for your help. So what is the difference between selenium+webdriver and your webXray then?

Comment: webxray uses phantomjs without selenium* and checks the domains to determine what is first- and third-party and sorts it for you

* the experimental version supports chrome but isn't yet released