# How can I set chrome settings in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to accept third party cookies in my chromedriver, this setting is off by default. How can I use chromedriver with accepting third party cookies enabled by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get 3rd party cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146514/how-to-get-3rd-party-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver_tab = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
for cookie in p_cookies:
    driver_tab.add_cookie(cookie)
```

p_cookies is a list of dict
you can use `driver.get_cookies()` after driver.get(url) or read from files